# How to prevent Windows from waking up HDD before shutdown?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, shutdown

I have a Windows 7 PC with a **SSD system drive** and a HDD. Most of my work is done on just SSD and HDD often went to sleep after a while, which is good. But when I shutdown the PC, it will wake up the HDD and it adds several seconds in delay. Not to mention the wear and tear on the HDD.

I searched on this topic and found a post here:

http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/365602-slow-shutdown-when-hard-disks-already-sleeping.html

which suggest that Windows need to flush write cache back to HDD. I am not convinced with the explanation at all. Write cache should have happened before Windows put the disk in sleep mode.

I would think that Windows is either trying to read or write to the HDD during shutdown. I would like to know what it is trying to do and if it is something that I can prevent.

Comment: The user who asked "how disable resume hard disk from Sleep on Shut Down" did not state up front that he is using an SSD as primary and therefore received answer not relevant to his question. I don't think his question is answered either.

Comment: The answer to that question is the same as for your question regardless of the use of SSD as a primary.

Comment: I'm not sure which answer you are referring to. In the end, the author of answer with +2 rating wasn't sure if he answered the question.